# Select field not Populating Choose value from dropdown array in Redux form

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I am able to populate the server response in the inner HTML page of the `select` field but while I am clicking on of the drop-down value, it doesn't select the chosen value.

It always selects the 1st value in the array.

Comment: you can send selected value in `initialValues`. Can you provide some code to reproduce same error.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/mZRjw05yp exmaple here